# Nested IF statements with AND or OR

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, if

I have a schedule that calculates total hours worked for the week and also calculates the number of employees present at opening and at closing.  The schedule is set up with nested IF statements to ignore the words "Off", "Vac", or "Flex".  Managers sometimes work split days so there are two rows for the managers and the schedule calculates total hours for both rows.  All works fine except I cannot figure out how to return a "1" for when either manager row has the manager present for opening or closing.  Cell F41 should be returning a "1" because the manager is present for the 10:00 AM opening.  I presume the problem is Cell F38, where I have generated a "0" to replace the word "Flex".  I can get F41 to return a correct value with "=IF(OR(D88<=0.416666666666667,D89<=0.416666666666667),1,0)" but the result fails with "Flex" entered in D88.  How can I get this cell to ignore the entered words and still return accurate opening and closing information?  If it matters, I am using Excel 2007.
TIA  Carl

Google Drive Link to File:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DBthdGpjVJqzBp5OyfpCyjfmaEIP6UPk/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113960402099335765622&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the way you've set up the formula, you're effectively saying

> If the first row contains any of the words Off, Vac or Flex, then return 0 [and don't do anything else]

The important thing here is that IF will exit as soon as the first condition it finds to be TRUE is met. So, it's found that F38 contains Flex, and it's stopped there. It is not placing a zero in row 38.

What you want is this:

> If either the first or second row is 10AM, then return 1, otherwise return 0

Any other values are irrelevant for this calculation.

I believe the reason you're having an issue with the word Flex is because you're comparing the cell with a decimal representation of the time. This should work:

```
=IF(OR(A1=TIME(10,0,0),A2=TIME(10,0,0)),1,0)
```

[image]

You can adapt this for your closing column, being sure to use `TIME(18,0,0)`.

Comment: I didn't know about the "time" function, thank you very much for introducing me to that.  Now, the store opens at 10 but the managers are scheduled for 9:30, so how do I get the formula to return a "1" for any time 10:00 or prior?  Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: You can just change it to `<=` instead of `=`

Comment: Cool, Thank you again.

Comment: @CarlFritsche, you're welcome. If the answer was useful and has solved your problem, please upvote the answer and mark it as accepted by clicking the check-mark next to the answer. Good luck with your studies!